# Magento2.3.4 - Switching Catalog Price Scope causes SQL error

Tags: database, magento2.3, error, reindex

After switching the Catalog Price Scope from Global to Website and trying to reindex I get the following SQL error. How do I fix it?

Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'cwd.default_store_id' in 'on clause', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `catalog_product_index_price_temp` SELECT `e`.`entity_id`,
>   `pw`.`website_id`, IF(IFNULL(tas_tax_class_id.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_tax_class_id.value, tad_tax_class_id.value) AS `tax_class_id`,
>   IFNULL((IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value)), 0) AS `price`,
>   IFNULL((LEAST(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value), IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value) IS NOT NULL AND
>   IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL OR
>   DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <=
>   cwd.website_date AND IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL OR
>   DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >=
>   cwd.website_date, IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value), ~0),
>   IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value_id is NULL AND tier_price_2.value_id is
>   NULL AND tier_price_3.value_id is NULL AND tier_price_4.value_id is
>   NULL, NULL, LEAST(IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_1.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_1.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_2.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_2.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_2.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_3.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_3.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_3.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_4.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_4.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_4.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0)))), ~0))), 0) AS `final_price`,
>   IFNULL((LEAST(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value), IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value) IS NOT NULL AND
>   IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL OR
>   DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <=
>   cwd.website_date AND IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL OR
>   DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >=
>   cwd.website_date, IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value), ~0),
>   IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value_id is NULL AND tier_price_2.value_id is
>   NULL AND tier_price_3.value_id is NULL AND tier_price_4.value_id is
>   NULL, NULL, LEAST(IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_1.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_1.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_2.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_2.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_2.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_3.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_3.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_3.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_4.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_4.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_4.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0)))), ~0))), 0) AS `min_price`,
>   IFNULL((LEAST(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value), IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value) IS NOT NULL AND
>   IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL OR
>   DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value)) <=
>   cwd.website_date AND IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL OR
>   DATE(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value)) >=
>   cwd.website_date, IF(IFNULL(tas_special_price.value_id, -1) > 0,
>   tas_special_price.value, tad_special_price.value), ~0),
>   IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value_id is NULL AND tier_price_2.value_id is
>   NULL AND tier_price_3.value_id is NULL AND tier_price_4.value_id is
>   NULL, NULL, LEAST(IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_1.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_1.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_2.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_2.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_2.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_3.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_3.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_3.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_4.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_4.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_4.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0)))), ~0))), 0) AS `max_price`, IF(tier_price_1.value_id is NULL AND
>   tier_price_2.value_id is NULL AND tier_price_3.value_id is NULL AND
>   tier_price_4.value_id is NULL, NULL,
>   LEAST(IFNULL((IF(tier_price_1.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_1.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_1.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_2.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_2.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_2.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_3.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_3.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_3.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0), IFNULL((IF(tier_price_4.value = 0,
>   ROUND(IF(IFNULL(tas_price.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_price.value,
>   tad_price.value) * (1 - ROUND(tier_price_4.percentage_value *
>   cwd.rate, 4) / 100), 4), ROUND(tier_price_4.value * cwd.rate, 4))),
>   ~0))) AS `tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`  LEFT JOIN
>   `mageworx_catalog_product_entity_decimal_temp` AS `tad_price` ON
>   tad_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_price.attribute_id = 214 AND
>   tad_price.store_id = 0  LEFT JOIN
>   `mageworx_catalog_product_entity_decimal_temp` AS `tas_price` ON
>   tas_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_price.attribute_id = 214 AND
>   tas_price.store_id = cwd.default_store_id  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_website` AS `pw` ON pw.product_id = e.entity_id 
>   INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON pw.website_id =
>   cwd.website_id  LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_tier_price` AS `tp`
>   ON tp.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tp.customer_group_id =
>   ta_price.customer_group_id AND tp.website_id = pw.website_id  LEFT
>   JOIN `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AS `tier_price_1` ON
>   tier_price_1.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tier_price_1.all_groups = 0
>   AND tier_price_1.customer_group_id = ta_price.customer_group_id AND
>   tier_price_1.qty = 1 AND tier_price_1.website_id = 0  LEFT JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AS `tier_price_2` ON
>   tier_price_2.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tier_price_2.all_groups = 0
>   AND tier_price_2.customer_group_id = ta_price.customer_group_id AND
>   tier_price_2.qty = 1 AND tier_price_2.website_id = pw.website_id  LEFT
>   JOIN `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AS `tier_price_3` ON
>   tier_price_3.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tier_price_3.all_groups = 1
>   AND tier_price_3.customer_group_id = 0 AND tier_price_3.qty = 1 AND
>   tier_price_3.website_id = 0  LEFT JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AS `tier_price_4` ON
>   tier_price_4.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tier_price_4.all_groups = 1
>   AND tier_price_4.customer_group_id = 0 AND tier_price_4.qty = 1 AND
>   tier_price_4.website_id = pw.website_id  LEFT JOIN
>   `mageworx_catalog_product_entity_decimal_temp` AS `tad_special_price`
>   ON tad_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tad_special_price.attribute_id = 215 AND tad_special_price.store_id =
>   0  LEFT JOIN `mageworx_catalog_product_entity_decimal_temp` AS
>   `tas_special_price` ON tas_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tas_special_price.attribute_id = 215 AND tas_special_price.store_id =
>   cwd.default_store_id  LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS
>   `tad_tax_class_id` ON tad_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tad_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 266 AND tad_tax_class_id.store_id = 0 
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_tax_class_id` ON
>   tas_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tas_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 266 AND tas_tax_class_id.store_id =
>   cwd.default_store_id  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS
>   `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tad_status.attribute_id = 234 AND tad_status.store_id = 0  LEFT JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id =
>   e.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 234 AND tas_status.store_id
>   = cwd.default_store_id  LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_to_date` ON tad_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id
>   AND tad_special_to_date.attribute_id = 217 AND
>   tad_special_to_date.store_id = 0  LEFT JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_to_date` ON
>   tas_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tas_special_to_date.attribute_id = 217 AND
>   tas_special_to_date.store_id = cwd.default_store_id  LEFT JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_from_date` ON
>   tad_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tad_special_from_date.attribute_id = 216 AND
>   tad_special_from_date.store_id = 0  LEFT JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_from_date` ON
>   tas_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
>   tas_special_from_date.attribute_id = 216 AND
>   tas_special_from_date.store_id = cwd.default_store_id WHERE
>   (IF(IFNULL(tas_status.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_status.value,
>   tad_status.value) = 1) AND (e.type_id = 'simple') AND (e.entity_id
>   BETWEEN 1 AND 1537)

Google Product Removal Feed index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Google Product Feed index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02